# Alternate construction of localization of a module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

I've been reading [this article](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/voloch/Preprints/fractions.pdf) by Voloch which gives an alternate construction of the localization $D^{-1}R$ of a ring $R$ via introducing an indeterminate $x_d$ for each $d \in D$ and quotienting by the ideal $\langle dx_d -1 \mid d \in D \rangle$. I was wondering if there was a corresponding construction for the localization of a module.

I know of the construction for $D^{-1}M$ via "fractions" or via tensoring with $S^{-1}R$. Maybe we could modify the last one...

Comment: What happens if you consider the module of "polynomials" wth coefficients in the module $M$ and variables $x_d$ one per $d\in D$ and divide by the analogous thing? Have you tried?

Comment: dear @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, apologies for digging up an old post, but do you mean the quotient construction that Eric presented below? if so I'm a little confused by it... for instance, given $m\in M$ and $u,v\in U$, do we have $u\cdot m_{uv}-m_v$ in the submodule that Eric quotients by? I don't think we do, although maybe I'm missing something

Comment: in fact, consider the case when $R=\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $M=\mathbb{Q}$, with $x$ acting as $0$. then the localization of $M$ at $U:=\{1,x,x^2,\dots\}$ is $\{0\}$, but if I'm not mistaken the quotient construction below yields $\bigoplus_{u\in U}\mathbb{Q}$, since the submodule quotiented by is just the first copy of $\mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could construct the localized module as $$\frac{M \oplus \left( \oplus_{u \in U} M \right)}{\langle m - u\cdot m_u \rangle },$$
but it's not clear why this would be edifying, because it doesn't have the nice universal properties that the ring case does. It's probably better to think of the localization as $M \otimes_R R[U^{-1}]$, and then prove the isomorphism to $M[U^{-1}]$, which is done in many books.

Comment: hi Eric; apologies for digging up an old post, but I'm a little confused about the quotient construction you give. for instance, given $m\in M$ and $u,v\in U$, do we have $u\cdot m_{uv}-m_v$ in the submodule you quotient by? I don't think we do, although maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom That's a good point. I think you're right, it doesn't work like it should. (Unless I'm also missing something)